# Insert statement does not insert any data

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, t-sql

I have a page where I display a list of groups for my application. There can be multiple users in a group. The group list is implemented with a gridview. Besides the column for the group description, the gridview has a button for adding users to it. When I click this button, the groupid is passed to a new page, on this page there is another gridview with a list of users. The gridview also has a buttonfield for adding that specific user to the group's group id. For this I have an extra table:

**UserGroup**

```
usergroupid
userid
groupid
```

My problem is, nothing is inserted into this table, the insert command is executed but something seems to be missing.

Here is my code:

Markup:

```
<asp:Content ID="content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">           
            <asp:GridView OnRowCommand="grdBenutzer_RowCommand" ID="grdBenutzer" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField ReadOnly="true" DataField="BenutzerID" HeaderText="ID" />                   
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Bezeichnung">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <%# Eval("Bezeichnung")%>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:DropDownList AppendDataBoundItems="true" runat="server" ID="ddwnBezeichnung" Text='<%# Bind("Bezeichnung")%>'>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="Mitarbeiter" Value="Mitarbeiter"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="Praktikant" Value="Praktikant"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="Azubi" Value="Azubi"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="Umschüler" Value="Umschüler"></asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Vorname">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <%# Eval("Vorname")%>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtVorname" Text='<%# Bind("Vorname")%>' />
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Nachname">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <%# Eval("Nachname")%>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtNachname" Text='<%# Bind("Nachname")%>' />
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:BoundField ReadOnly="true" HeaderText="Geburtsdatum" DataField="Geburtsdatum" />                    
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Benutzerart">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <%# Eval("Benutzerart")%>
                        </ItemTemplate>                        
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" HeaderText="Mitglied hinzufügen" Text="Mitglied hinzufügen" CommandName="MitgliedHinzufuegen" />
                </Columns>              
            </asp:GridView>
         <asp:SqlDataSource OnInserted="SqlDataSource1_Inserted" ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>"
            SelectCommand="SELECT [BenutzerID], [Bezeichnung], [Vorname], [Geburtsdatum], [Nachname], [Benutzerart] FROM [Benutzer] WHERE [Archiviert] != 1"
             InsertCommand="INSERT INTO BenutzerGruppe (BenutzerID, GruppenID) VALUES (@BenutzerID, @GruppenID)">                        
         </asp:SqlDataSource>
</asp:Content>
```

Code-behind:

```
protected void SqlDataSource1_Inserted(object sender, SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
{
            Response.Redirect("Gruppenverwaltung.aspx");
}

protected void grdBenutzer_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
            if (e.CommandName == "MitgliedHinzufuegen")
            {
                string gruppenid = Request.QueryString["GruppenID"];
                SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters.Add("GruppenID", gruppenid);               
                SqlDataSource1.Insert();
            }
}
```

The inserted method fires after I add an user to the group, but when I view the group's members, no user was added....

Comment: again you're doing the same mistake

Comment: sorry but as i said, i am very new to asp and sql and this is actually the first application that i am writing in this language...

Comment: ok thanks for the pointing out. i read your posts again and now it works :)

Answer (score 0):

The insert command expects input parameter @BenutzerID  which you don't appear to be providing in the code-behind.

Comment: I thought that the BenutzerID would be passed from the Select statement...i did it like this in my other queries

Comment: ok while debugging i noticed that you are right. what is a good way of passing the BenutzerID (UserID) from the selected User in the GridView?

Comment: Well, you need to add a line like this in your code: SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters.Add("BenutzerID", benutzerid); but I don't where benutzerid will come from, the query string perhaps like gruppenid?